# Nginx. How can I configure two vhost to have identical or almost identical server blocks?

Tags: nginx

Use case: in my team have the environment STAGE and PROD. Of course we want STAGE as close as possible to PROD and ideally we want to use the same config for both environments, so that if there are mistakes in it, hopefully they will be shown in STAGE rather than only in PROD.

Anyway the two enviroments aren't exactly identical and requires a few differences in directives.

For example

```
server {
  server_name prod.domain.tld;
  <block of directives, say block A>
}


server {
  server_name stage.domain.tld;
  <block of directives, say block A>
  <a couple more directives that are required for stage, very minimal>
}
```

What I tried:

#### approach 1 (didn't work)

The following didn't work because some directives could not be put within an `if`

```
server {
  server_name prod.domain.tld stage.domain.tld; #notice that everything is one block
  <block of directives, say block A>
  if ( $host = "stage.domain.tld" ) {
     <a couple more directives that are required for stage, very minimal>
  }
}
```

#### approach 2 (didn't work)

For the second approach I wanted to set variables with the default value, meant for PROD, and only in the case the host was STAGE the configuration would change the value to something else. But this was not possible either because some directives couldn't be simply turned off by special values (for example `add_header`) or other directives did not accept variables (`allow` for example).

```
server {
  server_name prod.domain.tld stage.domain.tld;
  <block of directives, say block A>
  <block of variables like: set $var1 default_value_for_prod>
  if ( $host = "stage.domain.tld" ) {
     <block of variables like: set $var1 value_for_stage>
  }
  <block of extra directives with the structure: directive $varN; >
}
```

#### approach 3 (works but it splits things around )

what I found that works is using includes, the drawback is that the configuration is scattered around in files.

```
server {
  server_name prod.domain.tld;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/common_configuration_stage_live;
}


server {
  server_name stage.domain.tld;
  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/common_configuration_stage_live;
  <a couple more directives that are required for stage, very minimal>
}
```

#### Final question

While approach 3 works, it is not great on the long run as configuration is split and one has to check multiple files (although it saves in redundancy). Do you have any other functioning way to achieve the goal?

Comment: You can use the approach 3, but just write the common configuration and add on server block the differences so it's possible share the common conf and add manually a specific configuration.

Comment: Third approach. And, next step is to put something like Ansible into the play, and that probably will turn your mind about scattered configurations and touching configurations by hand in principle.

Comment: @Roid thank you, though some directives require to be in the server block. If I understand you correctly you mean: put everything in the `http` block and only the differences in the `server` block.

@NikitaKipriyanov yes there is something like ansible at play (configuration management tools, or kube manifests) still when one has to debug the thing having split files around means that one has to reconstruct the config in one's head. Possible, yes, but some in the team dislike to have spaghetti configuration around.